# Select only most recent record for each group of records

Tags: c#, postgresql, linq, nhibernate

I have an db entity which looks like this:

```
public class History
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Text {get; set;}
    public DateTime DateTime {get; set;}
}
```

In db there can be multiple records with same `Text` value, and I need to fetch only those of them, which are the most recent (lastest) for each of the distinct 'Text' - so for each of `Text` value I should get only one latest record.

For example db table named history:

```
id | text | dateTime
---------------------
 1   abc     2018-01-05
 2   qqq     2018-01-08
 3   abc     2018-01-01
 4   qqq     2018-05-05
 5   abc     2018-01-03
```

the query result should be like this:

```
1 abc 2018-01-05
4 qqq 2018-05-05
```

Right now, using nHibernate I am doing this like that:

```
    var historyGroups = _session.Query<History>
        .OrderBy(x => x.DateTime)
        .GroupBy(x => x.Text)
        .ToArray();
```

and then selecting last item for each of group - but it fetches a lot of data that I don't need.

How to achieve that in more efficent way, via LINQ to SQL or via pure SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up using a raw SQL like this:

```
var data = _session.CreateSQLQuery("select distinct on (text) * from public.history 
order by text, datetime desc;")
.AddEntity(typeof(History))
.List<History>();
```

it returns the latest record per every distinct `Text` value.

Answer (score 0):

You should group *before* ordering:

```
var historyGroups = _session.Query<History>
    .GroupBy(x => x.Text)
    .Select(x => new { text = x.Key, latest = x.First(y => y.DateTime == x.Select(z => z.DateTime).Max()) })
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: your query selects the oldest not the latest record :)

Comment: I dont need the datetime for the specific key, rather the History element itself - I need the most recent History object for each of available 'Text' values. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: @pitersmx Ah, I see. Then you have a further indirection, you just have to select that element with the latest date. See my update.

Comment: Now, for each of keys there is always the same - the latest db History object, not necesarilly for the key Text value